# Cannot run a simple helloworld in gae (python 2.7)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to run the [official helloworld](https://shadyabhi@github.com/shadyabhi/helloworld.git) program in google-appengine 1.6.4 for python 2.7.

It's so frustrating to be not able to run a simple helloworld. I would appreciate any kind of help here.

Error I encounter:-

```
shadyabhi@MBP-archlinux ~/codes/gae $ dev_appserver.py helloworld/
INFO     2012-04-06 23:25:55,030 appengine_rpc.py:160] Server: appengine.google.com
INFO     2012-04-06 23:25:55,034 appcfg.py:582] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2012-04-06 23:25:56,709 appcfg.py:616] This SDK release is newer than the advertised release.
WARNING  2012-04-06 23:25:56,710 datastore_file_stub.py:513] Could not read datastore data from /tmp/dev_appserver.datastore
INFO     2012-04-06 23:25:56,773 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:647] Running application dev~helloworld on port 8080: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2012-04-06 23:25:56,774 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:649] Admin console is available at: http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
WARNING  2012-04-06 23:26:00,928 py_zipimport.py:139] Can't open zipfile /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11.egg-info: IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11.egg-info'
ERROR    2012-04-06 23:26:01,101 wsgi.py:189] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/google-appengine-python/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 187, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/opt/google-appengine-python/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in _LoadHandler
    raise ImportError('%s has no attribute %s' % (handler, name))
ImportError: <module 'helloworld' from '/home/shadyabhi/codes/gae/helloworld/helloworld.pyc'> has no attribute app
INFO     2012-04-06 23:26:01,110 dev_appserver.py:2884] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
ERROR    2012-04-06 23:26:01,479 wsgi.py:189] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/google-appengine-python/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 187, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/opt/google-appengine-python/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in _LoadHandler
    raise ImportError('%s has no attribute %s' % (handler, name))
ImportError: <module 'helloworld' from '/home/shadyabhi/codes/gae/helloworld/helloworld.pyc'> has no attribute app
INFO     2012-04-06 23:26:01,486 dev_appserver.py:2884] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One difference between the files that you have on github and the [official google hellworld tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld) is that your helloworld file doesn't seem to be named helloworld.py.  Potentially that would help?

Additionally, do you need that PROJECT_DIR variable at the top of helloworld?

If you are struggling to get the basic tutorial working, the first thing you should do is make sure that your project is literally the exact same as the google example.

Comment: Can I do anything about the warning `WARNING  2012-04-07 19:18:24,054 py_zipimport.py:139] Can't open zipfile /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11.egg-info: IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11.egg-info'
`?

Comment: The warning is harmless.  However, google doesn't let you import from the site-packages directory so you could probably fix this via your pythonpath.

Comment: There's no way memcache has anything to do with this, or any reason to think it would.

Comment: @NickJohnson thanks, I've edited out the mention of memcache.  It seemed to be a very common solution to what looked like a similar problem to what the OP was having.  I have 0 experience with GAE, only answered because of the problems that I could see in the original question.

Answer (score 36):

If you're using python2.7 libraries there's an error with the tutorial

This line is incorrect:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

The correct line should be:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

The WSGI handler is complaining because it is looking for an attribute called "app".

Comment: Surprisingly, this answer worked for me as well! I had named my application as `application` and the compiler kept on complaining about it! I changed it to app and wallah... I was back! Thanks!

Comment: I landed here from Google and found the exact opposite situation to be my problem. That is, I had `app = ...` but it needed to be `application = ...`

Comment: There is a mismatch between the .py and the .yaml files. You could fix either. in the yaml, edit the line "script: webapp.application"

Answer (score 1):

by checking your git repo i see helloworld is not a .py file.
rename it to helloworld.py and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code did the trick for me (notice 'application' replaced with 'app'):

```
app = webapp.WSGIApplication(
  [('/', MainHandler),
    ('/upload', UploadHandler),
    ('/serve/([^/]+)?', ServeHandler),
  ], debug=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  run_wsgi_app(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a 500 error after I copied the code straight off Google's site. None of the above worked.

All I had to do was change the indentation for each line of code (i.e. change the spaces to Tabs) and bingo.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When using runtime python 2.7 you don't have to use the main function

Remove this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
      run_wsgi_app(app)
```

and simply call

```
app = webapp.WSGIApplication(
[('/', MainHandler),
('/upload', UploadHandler), 
('/serve/([^/]+)?', ServeHandler),], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on the [official hello world](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld) tutorial in python 2.7 and found the same mistake in the configuration file app.yaml
The last line reads

script: helloworld.application

*it should be*

script: helloworld.app