# How do I run custom python script in Google App engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, pip, gcloud

Apologies for the long detailed question. Here goes...

The file has the name send_daily_report.py and uses some libraries which are detailed in a requirements.txt file.

My ***app.yaml*** looks as follows:

```
runtime: python27
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /send_daily_report
  script: send_daily_report.py

libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

My ***cron.yaml*** looks as follows:

```
cron:
- description: "Send unsent subscriptions to Glocell rewards every 1 minute"
  url: /send_daily_report
  schedule: every 1 day from 00:00
```

And finally my ***requirements.txt*** has the following contents:

```
Babel==2.5.3
cachetools==3.1.0
certifi==2017.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
coloredlogs==8.0
colorlog==3.1.0
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
google-api-core==1.10.0
google-auth==1.6.3
google-cloud-core==0.29.1
google-cloud-storage==1.15.0
google-resumable-media==0.3.2
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.10
humanfriendly==4.6
idna==2.6
jdcal==1.3
money==1.3.0
mysql-connector-python==8.0.5
mysqlclient==1.3.12
numpy==1.16.3
openpyxl==2.5.0
pandas==0.24.2
protobuf==3.7.1
pyasn1==0.4.5
pyasn1-modules==0.2.5
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-magic==0.4.15
pytz==2017.3
requests==2.18.4
rsa==4.0
six==1.12.0
urllib3==1.22
```

When I do a:

> gcloud app deploy app.yaml cron.yaml

it seems to ignore my requirements.txt and doesn't install the dependent. I even ran it in the gcloud dev server ([dev_appserver.py](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server) ./app.yaml --enable_console) locally and the libraries are definitely not being installed when I use the dev server console to try and import them.

I then tried to use Python 3.7. which actually installs the libraries in requirements.txt but the problem is in the app.yaml in the handlers I cannot specify the script name. For python 3.7 that value is always set to auto as per the [gcloud app.yaml reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref).

What do I need to do to execute my script in gcloud app engine cron. On a linux system this would have been a simple cronjob setup in the crontab as follows:

> 0 0 * * * python /send_daily_py

From what i'm reading about Python 3.7, it seems like I need to have django or flex to handle the requests and route them to execute my custom .py script which seems like overkill just so that I can execute one script. Surely there is a way around this?. I even tried to include the libraries in a subfolder within my app folder as follows:

> pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt -t ./lib

Then I added **init**.py within lib, and then I changed all my imports to use

> import lib.name_of_library

Which did not work as those libraries could subsequently not import sub packages they need.

**

### Heeeeelp!

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine is PaaS product, not an IaaS one (on which you could, indeed, just run a linux image and install the cron you mentioned). You cannot run arbitrary **standalone** python scrips in GAE. You *might* be able to achieve what you want by re-working the script to meet the GAE apps requirements - basically make the functionality callable from inside a HTTP(S) handler.

For the 1st generation standard environment (python27 runtime):

- the `requirements.txt` file isn't used by GAE. As you discovered, you can use it to vendor in your python dependencies, but there's more to do, see [Copying a third-party library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library).
- your script functionality needs to be re-worked as a WSGI app, which is what you configure in your `app.yaml`. From [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element):

> A **script:** directive must be a python import path, for example,
>   **package.module.app** that points to a WSGI application. The last component of a **script:** directive using a **Python module** path is
>   the name of a global variable in the module: that variable must be a
>   WSGI app, and is usually called ** ** by convention.
>
> Note: just like for a Python **import** statement, each subdirectory
>   that is a package must contain a file named [**init**.py](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

- I'd suggest you go through [Python Runtime Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime), your long list of requirements *might* not meet the sandbox limitations (in particular the [Pure Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime#Python_Pure_Python) one).

For the 2nd generation standard environment (python37 runtime):

- dependencies are automatically installed from your `requirements.txt` file, see [Specifying Dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies)
- only `auto` can be specified in a `script:` statement in `app.yaml`, because the app itself is specified via the `entrypoint:` config. So you need need to rework your script to be invoked as handler in that app. From [Runtime and app elements](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#runtime_and_app_elements):

> For your app to receive HTTP requests, **entrypoint** should contain a
>   command which starts a web server that listens on the port specified
>   by the PORT environment variable.

The [flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/) (with similar re-work as for the 2nd gen standard one) could be a better fit, especially because you can configure instances with more ram/cpu resources (which you *might* need judging by your `requirements.txt` file) than in the standard environment.

Comment: how do I create a handler app for app engine? I know django, but like I mentioned its a bit of an overkill. I assume and need to google my assumption  but i could include a wsgi package and map different paths to some sort of view/controller or script?

Comment: Could I use Flask as per this https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-web-app-using-pythons-flask-and-google-app-engine-52b1bb82b221 ?

Comment: For Django see some pointers in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33307783/4495081. Flask is also OK. Personally I'm using the simpler [webapp2](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Let me try it and if i succeed il mark this as correct. Thanks

Comment: Worked! Used Flask.

Comment: @Dean how did you manage to create that custom handler using Flask? I'm also stuck with the "script: auto" limitation.

Comment: @cjlallana in my app.yaml i ended up  with the following line only and removed the whole script: auto thing - runtime: python37. And then i added flask framework to my requirements.txt with the following line: flask==1.0.2. Then I created a the flask controller main.py which is the one that handles the routing. Full instructions on flask here http://flask.pocoo.org